In Rust doctest, why can't I use a public static function?
Here is a short example:
//!   
//! example:
//!  
//!```
//!
//!         use nalgebra::{Quaternion, UnitQuaternion, Vector3};
//! // use crate::naive_cf::NaiveCF;
//!
//! let acc = Vector3::new(3.64637947, 5.30298471, 6.84866046);
//!
//!         let rotation = UnitQuaternion::from_quaternion(Quaternion::new(
//!             0.60163784,
//!             -0.0844770521,
//!            0.269781291,
//!            -0.614157497,
//!        ));
//!
//! let v = NaiveCF::new();
//!        // let v = NaiveCF::get_correction_verified(&acc, &rotation);
//! ```

use crate::{ARGlasses, Error, Fusion, GlassesEvent};
use nalgebra::{Quaternion, UnitQuaternion, Vector3};

#[cfg(doctest)]
pub fn bar() {
    println!("hello");
    let v = NaiveCF::new();
}

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>;

pub struct NaiveCF {
...
}

impl NaiveCF {
    pub fn new(glasses: Box<dyn ARGlasses>) -> Result<Self> {
        ...
    }

...


When running cargo test, I observe 2 symptoms:

bar() is ignored, it can be compiled successfully tho
the doctest at example can be detected, but running it cause the following error:

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `NaiveCF`
  --> src/naive_cf.rs:43:10
   |
16 |  let v = NaiveCF::new();
   |          ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `NaiveCF`

error: aborting due to 1 previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
Couldn't compile the test.

error: doctest failed, to rerun pass `--doc`
error: 1 target failed:
    `--doc`

which is strange as NaiveCF is in the same crate.
How could these problem happens, and how to fix them?

Being in the same crate does not suffice, it must also be in scope (for example by useing it) please add a [mre] including your module layout.

Doctests are integration tests which must use the crate as another crate would.

@cafce25: That's an answer, not a comment. Though I would expect we've got a duplicate already... it's a bit of quirky behavior, so surely someone already asked.

@MatthiouM You're right, maybe How can I use a custom module inside a doctest?. At the time I didn't find this.
